# Script Editor - Load Data from multiple lists on button click into table

Tags: web-part, jquery, script

I've been struggling with this code for over a week and I wanted to see if I could get some feedback on the idea itself of what I am trying to accomplish.

What I want to do is inside of a script editor web part, I want to have filters (dropdowns/textboxes/etc) and a button that will populate all of the data based on these filters when clicked.

When the button is clicked, I need to run a function that checks to see if a list exists because I have many lists that could possibly exist - due to the fact that I had to create separate lists that were less than 5000 items each because of some problems I ran into having a list of data too long.

So if a list exists, I need to get all of the data for that list, and continue doing so for every list that exists inside of a loop referencing the sequentially labeled list name.

This data should populate in the order that the lists are retrieved. And multiple users would use this feature at the same time.

The reason I am doing this is because I have limited access to the development side of the project and the built-in list functionality will not display the data the way that I need to have it grouped.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Script Editor webpart. HTML can be written to create filters (textboxes, dropdowns etc) and Javascript client object model code can be used to access data in lists. Finally, you can show the data in a table (Look for [Jquery Datatable Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/)). The datatable plugin provides several great functions like Search, paging, sorting etc.

Comment: thanks, I was looking at that plugin - I've accomplished most of what I've tried to do but I keep getting errors on lists being initialized, I'll mark yours as the answer that what I am doing is plausible and create a new question regarding my current coding problem

Comment: I created the detailed question here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121112/getenumerator-causing-collection-has-not-been-initialized-error-inside-of-async